# What code should be written to create a new variable from observations containing the same content in the R column?

Tags: r

My variable is as follows

| variable |
| --- |
| D |
| D |
| B |
| C |
| B |
| D |
| C |
| C |
| D |

I want to make the column in the above figure below

| variable | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 |

But I don't want a code like the one below. Because the number of factors in the variable column is too many

```
data = data %>% mutate(B=ifelse(variable=="B", 1,0),
                       C=ifelse(variable=="C", 1,0),
                       D=ifelse(variable=="D", 1,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R approach.  We can first find all unique `variable` values from the data frame.  Then, `sapply` over that vector and generate a new column for each value.  Finally, we can `rbind` this new data frame of 0/1 valued columns to the original data frame.

```r
cols <- sort(unique(df$variable))
df2 <- sapply(cols, function(x) ifelse(df$variable == x, 1, 0))
df <- cbind(df, df2)
df

  variable B C D
1        D 0 0 1
2        D 0 0 1
3        B 1 0 0
4        C 0 1 0
5        B 1 0 0
6        D 0 0 1
7        C 0 1 0
8        C 0 1 0
9        D 0 0 1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(variable=c("D", "D", "B", "C", "B",
                            "D", "C", "C", "D"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with reshaping and duplicating the original variable in order to have a reference for values. Then, you can reshape to obtain the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% mutate(Var=variable,Val=1,id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=Val,values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  variable     D     B     C
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 D            1     0     0
2 D            1     0     0
3 B            0     1     0
4 C            0     0     1
5 B            0     1     0
6 D            1     0     0
7 C            0     0     1
8 C            0     0     1
9 D            1     0     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(variable = c("D", "D", "B", "C", "B", "D", "C", 
"C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) model.matrix**

`model.matrix` will generate column names like `variableB` so the last line removes the `variable` part to ensure that the column names are exactly the same as in the question.  Omit the last line if it is not important that the column names be exactly as shown there.

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat, model.matrix(~ variable - 1, dat))
names(dat2) <- sub("variable(.)", "\\1", names(dat2))
```

giving:

```
> dat2
  variable B C D
1        D 0 0 1
2        D 0 0 1
3        B 1 0 0
4        C 0 1 0
5        B 1 0 0
6        D 0 0 1
7        C 0 1 0
8        C 0 1 0
9        D 0 0 1
```

**2) outer**

This can also be done using `outer` as shown. Each component of `variable` is compared to each level.  We name the levels so that `outer` uses them as column names. The output is the same.

```
levs <- sort(unique(dat$variable))
names(levs) <- levs
cbind(dat, +outer(dat$variable, levs, `==`))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
variable
D
D
B
C
B
D
C
C
D"
dat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```